# how can I compare that a string is a part of a large string , both strings are store in different array index

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've two arrays containing different strings in their index's and i want to compare these string to ensure that one string is either a sub string of other or not. for example

```
$final_array=array("BSSE (English) Mr. John","BSSE (Physics) Mr. jack","BSSE (Math) Mr. peter");
$teachers=array("Mr.John","Mr. peter","Mr. jack");
```

now I want to get all the classes that Mr. john teaches by comparing "teachers array" index with all the indexes of "final_array" to get the elements have a string part Mr. John..
I hope you people can understand my problem

Comment: You can use `strpos()`, though there might be better ways and this will not take care of two teachers with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this will only work if the teacher names are unique and if the teachers names are spelled the same in both arrays.

This loops through all the teachers and compares each teacher string with each class string. If the teacher name exists in one of the class names the code will run through the if statement.

```
foreach($teachers as $teacher) {
    foreach($final_array as $class) {
        if(strpos($class, $teacher) !== FALSE) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to remove spaces from your strings

`$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);`

Also make that string all lowercase

`$string = strtolower($string);`

That way, the comparison between the positions of the arrays will be easier:

```
$tcounter = 0;
$ccounter = 0;  
    foreach($teachers as $teacher) {
        $tname = strtolower(str_replace(' ','', $teacher));
        $tcounter ++;
        foreach($final_array as $class) {
            $cname = strtolower(str_replace(' ','', $class)); 
            if(strpos($cname, $tname) !== FALSE) {
                echo '$teachers["'.$tcounter.'"] found on $final_array["'.$ccounter.'"]'; 
            }
            $ccounter++;
        }
        $ccounter=0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks David Bm... Its great